# Selecting multiple images in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this html:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">
<img ng-src="img/{{image}}_off.png" />
</div>
```

And this javascript in the controller:

```
$scope.images = ['imga','imgb','imgc'];
```

I also have these image files:

```
imga_off
imga_on
imgb_off
imgb_on
imgc_off
imgc_on
```

What I need is to switch between on and off when an image is clicked.

Im not really sure what the best approach is.
Is it about attaching an ng-model for each img-element?
Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold toggle data in `$scope` variable:

`var $scope.toggles = [false, false, false];`

Toggle based on `$index`:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">
  <img ng-src="img/{{image}}_{{ toggles[$index] ? 'on' : 'off' }}.png" ng-click="toggles[$index] = !toggles[$index]"/>
</div>
```

Note: This code is untested but this is a general approach. You could also hold toggle data as part of `$scope.images`